# Habilitación de botón apartir de un desplegable jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

tengo varios desplegables con su respectivo botón, he realizado  la que me funcionen en dos de los botones pero en los otros dos no consigo. Estoy aplicando la misma función para todos.

```
$("[id$=Bausch]").change(function() 
  { 
      if ($("[id$=Bausch]").val() == 0)
      {
        $("[id$=btnParadaEti]").attr("disabled", true); 
        $("[id$=btnFinal]").attr("disabled", false);
        $("[id$=btnParadaEst]").attr("disabled", true); 
       } 
      else     
     { 
        $("[id$=btnParadaEti]").removeAttr("disabled"); 

      } 
   });
```

Este el primero y me funciona correctamente.

```
$("[id$=Dividella]").change(function() 
    { 
      if ($("[id$=Dividella]").val() == 0) 
      { 
      $("[id$=btnParadaEst]").attr("disabled", true); 

     } 
     else 
     {

         $("[id$=btnParadaEst]").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        $("[id$=btnFinal]").attr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
```

Este es el segundo y no me funciona. Dejo el html en caso de corrección.

```
<td>
  <asp:Label ID="labelDividella" Text="Estuchadora" class="Info_Label" runat="server" style="font-size:20px;" /><br></br>
  <img src="../Resources/dividella.png" style="width:187px; height:100px; padding-right:25px" alt="DIVIDELLA"></img><br/>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="Dividella" runat="server" style="font-size:25px; width:200px;">

    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" value=""> </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="Ajustes"> Ajustes </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="Ajustes"> Ajuste de cámara </asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList><br></br>
  <span id="estilo"> 
    <Button ID="btnParadaEst"  Class="ButtonAction AbreDialogFirma"
                                        onMouseOver="this.className='ButtonActionOver';"

onmouseout="this.className='ButtonAction';" runat="server">Parada
                                       </Button>   </span>
</td>
```

Alguna idea porque razón no funciona correctamente

Comment: Estimado, no se entiende mucho tu código, por favor ordena dentro de 1 solo código el javascript junto con el html para detectar que corresponde a que!

Comment: ya lo he corregido. Gracias